# using jQuery Positioning... The positioning doesn't stay fixed to the element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, positioning

I'm using the jQuery positioning plugin from jQuery UI:

http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138026/Position

Positioning works well enough to set a item next to an existing item on the page. the problem is if the item on the page moves or goes away, then the positioned item stays there and doesn't get removed or reposition.

Is there a way to make positioning an item dynamic based on the anchor element? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Position()` just sets the element to a position relative to given element one time and doesn't watch for it's movement afterwards. If the element to which you're positioning another one changes position you have to call `position()` again. If it animates, you'll have to animate both elements.